# Condition number of orthogonal matrices induced by the L1 norm

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, condition-number

It is easy to prove that condition number for an orthogonal matrix $A$, $\kappa (A) = 1$ when induced by the $L2$ norm using the fact that:
$$
||A||_2 = \text{maximum eigenvalue of }A^TA
$$
But how can we compute condition number for the $L1$ norm? Or in general for the $Lp$ norm?

Comment: Are you asking what the condition number of orthogonal matrix is in the $l_p$ norms? Take a rotation of ${\pi \over 4}$ in the plane, the $l_1$ norm is $\sqrt{2}$. Hence the condition number is $2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you expand on that a bit? How did you get the value $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: It it a straightforward computation?

Comment: It is not too hard to see geometricly. Look at how rotation can affect an element of the $l_1$ sphere.

Comment: Yes, I understood. This answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/994948/724413) confused me and I thought condition number would be 1 for orthogonal matrices for all $p$ norms.

Comment: That result is true for orthogonal matrices and the $l_2$ norm.